# RMI and references / Proxy classes

Tags: java, rmi

As far as I can see, given a `IFoo` interface extending `Remote` and a `FooImpl` class implementing `IFoo`,  the following two code fragments are (almost) equivalent : (1)

```
IFoo stub = ( IFoo )UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject( new FooImpl() );
Naming.bind( "foo", stub );
```

and, if `FooImpl` is a class that extends `UnicastRemoteObject` : (2)

```
Naming.bind( "foo", new FooImpl() );
```

In fact, the `FooImpl` instance exportation is done in the implicit `UnicastRemoteObject` constructor call.

But in (1), the object returned by `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` is a `Proxy` (dynamic) class, and consequently the object recorded in the RMI registry is obviously a reference. Whereas in (2), it is not clear.

Where is the `Proxy` construction based an a `FooImpl` instance realized ? I have seen that the RMI registry management in the client code (`Naming.bind()`) encapsulates a (registry) `Proxy` class creation with a call to `LocateRegistry.getRegister()`. So in the request :

```
Naming.bind( "foo", new FooImpl() )
```

is it the registry `Proxy` class invocation handler that handles the parameters extending `Remote` to transform them as references / `Proxy` classes ?

And in that case, given that the stub `Proxy` class in (1) is itself a `Remote` class, would that mean that the object stored in the registry is a reference to a reference (i.e. a `Proxy` calling another `Proxy` calling the real class) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the FooImpl object is marshalled to the Registry in the bind() call it is automatically replaced by its stub. That happens for any exported remote object when used as a parameter or result of a remote method.

Comment: Thanks. Does it imply that in (1), `Naming.bind( "foo", new FooImpl() );` should be preferred to `Naming.bind( "foo", stub );` ?

Comment: @ysomane On the contrary, it implies that it doesn't make any difference. You might have other reasons for preferring the second, e.g. retaining a reference to the remote object so you can unexport it.